# Visual Studio 2013 install the same add on extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I am installing Visual Studio 2013 on a new machine.  How could I install the same extensions that my old machine has without download them and reinstall them one at a time from the online repository?  These are not the packages that can be restored when a solution is opened by clicking the Manage Nuget Packages for Solution in the Solution Explorer context menu.  They are just the Extension and Update in the Tools menu while no solution is opened.  Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040116/sync-extensions-in-visual-studio-2013-between-multiple-machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension called [Export Extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bede104c-8b57-4649-8777-b994b3b63abc) which creates cmd file, that you can run on the second PC and this will download/install all extensions again if it can find all download links on visual studio gallery.

> This extensions provides an ability to package current list of Visual
>   Studio Extensions into CMD file.
>
> Later on  you can simply execute that cmd file to download and install
>   the same list of extensions on fresh installation and other machine.
>
> - Install Extension
> - Go to Tools->Export Extensions
> - Pick a name and location of the CMD script
> - Click 'Save'

Comment: Along the same lines there's also the "Roaming Extension manager" https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7b421a95-c32c-4433-a2be-a41b276013ab for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: as well as the Suggested Extensions Extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3be88243-8bf1-407a-a7ca-a968d0de2d59

Comment: @jessehouwing he is using VS2013, so the extensions are useless for him ;)

Comment: I know, but other will find the question and find more useful extensions this way.

Comment: @jessehouwing they won't because they look for questions with VS2015 tag if they use 2015

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.  I installed the Export Extensions with VS2013.  I successfully created the CMD script.  I jet need to see if this script work for vs2015 on my new computer.

Comment: that can be an issue. Not all extension work for VS2013/2015. Some are 2013 only and have a special 2015 version